# Can a Diagram have multiple linktemplates Gojs？

Tags: javascript, gojs

What I want to do: click the link style in the right Palette to draw different styles of link in the Diagram. I tried it with linkTemplateMap.add but it not working. Please help me!!!

[image]

```
myDiagram.linkTemplateMap.add("Support",
  $(go.Link, go.Link.Bezier,
    { isLayoutPositioned: false, isTreeLink: false, curviness: -50 },
    { relinkableFrom: true, relinkableTo: true },
    $(go.Shape,
      { stroke: "green", strokeWidth: 2 }),
    $(go.Shape,
      { toArrow: "OpenTriangle", stroke: "green", strokeWidth: 2 }),
    $(go.TextBlock,
      new go.Binding("text", "text"),
      { stroke: "green", background: "rgba(255,255,255,0.75)",
        maxSize: new go.Size(80, NaN)
      })));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you change the link template for both the Palette and the Diagram.

If you define them on the diagram, you can set

```
myPalette.linkTemplateMap = myDiagram.linkTemplateMap;
```